# How to 'pre increment' a BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, math, biginteger

I have a `for` loop with `BigInteger`s, something like this:

```
for(BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(1); a.compareTo(someBigInteger); ++a) {...
```

Obviously I can't use the `++` operator on a non-primitive. How do I work around this?

Also, I have to use `BigInteger` in this scenario.

Comment: Well... just add 1. BTW don't use `BigInteger.valueOf` for values that are defined statically (for example `ONE`), especially if it is going to be executed many times

Comment: By the way, `++a` is not post increment.

Comment: Just add one to it and reassign the variable to that result.

Comment: Is it really that hard to google thing like this? Did you honestly try looking?

Comment: I confused pre increment and post increment. Instead of giving me multiple downvotes you could have just explained me that in a for loop there is no difference which one I use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`++a` is a prefix increment, not a postfix increment, but in the context of a for-loop it doesn't really matter, as you ignore the return value of that statement anyway. In any event, this functionality could be acheieved by calling [`BigInteger.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add-java.math.BigInteger-). Also note that `compareTo` returns an `int`, and since Java does not have implicit casts between `int`s and `boolean`s (like, e.g., C does), you'd have to compare its result to 0 to see if `a` is smaller, larger or equal to `someBigInteger`):

```
for (BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE; 
     a.compareTo(someBigInteger) < 0; 
     a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {...
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question since I didn't know that in a for loop there is no difference between a preincrement and a postincrement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redefine the operator ++ to work with BigInteger, so the solution is the trivial one:
1) First declare a BigInteger and initialize it
2) In the loop, reassign the BigInteger (a new BigInteger is created when invoking the add method);

```
private static final BigInteger LIMIT = new BigInteger("10");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BigInteger("0");    
    for (BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO; a.compareTo(LIMIT) < 0; a = a.add(new BigInteger("1")))
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

Refer to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)

Comment: Why do we need to mention new in the add method

Comment: creating a new `BigInteger` from a string on every iteration seems pretty inefficient, especially when you have `BigInteger.ONE` already constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like this.

for(BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE; a.compareTo(someBigInteger); a=a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {.